# Can we lost any settings if we update plugin by single click?

Tags: wordpress

I have a wordpress website. It will ask to update plugin again and again. So if i do these plugin update by clicking on update button, will any settings of plugin be lost ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether plugin will get lost all previous setting or not, it is totally dependent on plugin logic.

E.g. I can develop a WordPress plugin which if somebody installs and updates later, can erase all previous setting. I can write a logic like that. So you can simply ask the same question to plugin developer as they can give you perfect answer.

Comment: E.g we put some settings when we install contact form 7 plugin to theme, then we put some settings like email id etc. If we update plugin then these setting will be there or we have to put these settings again ?

Comment: I don't think it will erase data given that you're updating the plugin on the same site and with the same domain. 

Just for safety, you can take a backup of database from cpanel in that case.